# Java: Finding the least common multiple of two positive integers, within a recursive method, with 2 parameters, and with no other loops or methods

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I'm trying to write a recursive method for an extra credit homework assignment, that finds the least common multiple of two positive integers. However the method needs to follow these rules...

1. The method must be static with only two int parameters
2. The method must be recursive, and cannot use any loops
3. The method can not call any other methods, nor can it call any overloaded methods
4. The method returns the least common multiple of the arguments passed to it

My question is, is this even possible without a third parameter?

Let's say the parameters (a, b) have (6, 8) passed as arguments.

```
public static int findLCM (int a, int b) {
    if (a % b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return findLCM(a + a, b);
}
```

What I wanted to do was increase 6 to 12, and make a recursive call with findLCM(12, 8), then 12 would be 18, then finally 24. Since (24 % 8 == 0) then 24 would be the LCM.

However as you can clearly see, this code does not do that, because the statement

```
return findLCM(a + a, b);
```

would only work with a thrid parameter, then rewritten as

```
return findLCM(a + originalA, b);
```

I can't seem to find any way it would be possible without adding a 3rd parameter.

I've tried other approaches such as getting the greatest common denominator first, and then using it to find the least common multiple, but it seems this is just not possible without other methods, or at least loops.

```
// Doesn't work. Attempts to get greatest common denominator first, then apply the formula to find the LCM at the first instance of the method being called
// but there seems to be no way to really detect when to apply this final formula
public static int findLCM (int a, int b) {
    int result;
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else { 
        result = findLCM(b, a % b);
        // When to return gcd, or return lcm???
        if (result == b)
            return result; 
        else
            return (a * b) / result; // formula for lcm
    }
}
```

I've thought of trying prime factorization, and then using that to find the lcm, but I'm sure that will have the same problem as getting the gcd and then finding the lcm. It's just not possible without other methods or loops.

I apologize if this question isn't completely coding related, but I would just like to know does any one see something I am missing? Is there actually a way to recursively find the lcm with just two parameters, and no loops or other method calls. Or have I been wracking my brain for nothing? This is a simple java class, I feel like it really shouldn't be this hard. Either the assignment is impossible, or I'm missing something obvious...

Thanks for any help

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." (where homework includes any type of "homework", whether it's for school, work, a challenge, etc.)

Comment: Your sample code is irrelevant to the question you are asking.

Comment: So are you having trouble with the code or with the maths?

Comment: @vanza I guess I'm having trouble with the math, but I just don't see how it's possible with without loops, additional methods, or additional parameters. I honestly think this challenge may have a mistake, but I don't want to dismiss it until I can get a second opinion.

Comment: In that case, rephrase your question so that you explain the algorithm you're trying to implement, and why you're having trouble implementing it in a non-recursive manner. The way it is, the question has nothing to do with coding at all.

Comment: @vanza I've rephrased my question, is it more appropriate then the original? Thank you for your help

Comment: The answer to your questions is "no". But back to my comment, try to describe *your algorithm*. You haven't described it anywhere (except implicitly in your broken code). Then show why do you think you need any of the things you're asking about. We can't help if we don't know what you're thinking (and I wouldn't count just writing down the answer as helping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... a rather hacky solution would be to use negative values to tell the function to calculate the biggest common dominator and then use its relation to lcm:

```
int public lcm(int a, int b) {
  if (a >= 0 && b >= 0) {
    long gcd = lcm(-a, -b);
    return (a * b) / gcd;   // lcm(a,b) * gcd(a,b) == |a*b|
  }
  // here we simulate euclid's gcd()
  a = -a;
  b = -b;
  if (b == 0)
    return a;
  else
    return lcm(-b, -(a%b)); // neg -> simulate gcd()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cool solution!! Hope it would work for all the inputs.

```
public class LCM
{ 
  static int i=1;
  public static void main(String s[])
  {
    System.out.print(lcm(112,34));
  }

  public static int lcm(int a,int b)
  {   
     if(a%b==0)
        return a;
     else
        return lcm(a+a/i++,b);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will find the Lowest commun multiplier and the greatest commun factor

```
//Get Lowest Common Multiplier
public int LCM(int a, int b) {
    return (a * b) / GCF(a, b);
}

//Get Greatest Common Factor
private int GCF(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return (GCF(b, a % b));
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see my point? this comment you copy and paste it in all my post with no reason, please learn hoe to make profesional opinions the namig convention here are the initials of the funtion, but again it is pure technicality, could be change without a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int lcm(int a, int b) {
    return (a == 0 || b == 0) ? a + b : lcm(Math.max(a, b) - Math.min(a, b), Math.min(a, b));
}
```

if you want a short version